# The threat of your app being decompiled and modified to bombard parse

Tags: parse-platform

Are there any preventive measures that stop a scenario where a person decompiles my app and modifies my `PFObject` so that it generates new and random data properties/classes in my Parse database?

Right now, my app would `registerSubclass` based on what I've defined in my code. What's stopping the people who decompiles my app, adds a new class, and registers it to the database?

Comment: Turn off client class creation if you don't want this behaviour. In my opinion, you should never run a production/public application with this functionality on anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @rickerbh correctly pointed out in his comment, turn off client-side class creation, make sure that you have proper ACLs set for your objects and make use of the class-level permissions (CLP) on your collections to control who can perform what sort of operations on them.

Parse has some security related blog posts you should definitely read as well, all these measures should give you a good level of security if used correctly.

http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/parse-security-i-are-you-the-key-master/
http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/parse-security-ii-class-hysteria/
http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/parse-security-iii-are-you-on-the-list/
http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/parse-security-iv-ahead-in-the-cloud/
http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/parse-security-v-how-to-make-friends/
http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/parse-security-vi-quiz-time/